# Is java.io.FileWriter designed only for a single use?

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm building a program that constantly writes to the same file, using `java.io.FileWriter`.

During run-time, whenever I need to update the file, I call a method that [writes "properly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887520/java-create-temp-file-and-replace-with-original) and uses a class-level FileWriter. The problem starts on the second `.write` call, when the FileWriter starts **appending** to the file, instead of **overwriting** it.

```
public class Example {
    private FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file's path", false);

    public void writeToFile(String output) {
        fw.write(output);
        fw.flush();
    }
}
```

I'm suspecting that somehow the FileWriter's "memory" keeps its previously written data, but I don't want to close and initialize it for every call, as it seems wasteful.

1. Do I even need the `.flush` call after each `.write` call?
2. Do I have another option but initializing the FileWriter and `.close`-ing it on every call?

(I tried looking in older questions, but they all seem to deal with FileWriters that **won't** append, or theoretical `FileWriter.flush` interpretations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writer` (of which `FileWriter` is a subclass) is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) to work in a stream-oriented model, vs. for instance a random access one. Consecutive writes via the same `Writer` instance always append. To overwrite an existing file, you need to construct a new `FileWriter` instance every time. It is actually a fairly cheap operation anyway.

Answer (score 21):

> The problem starts on the second .write call, when the FileWriter starts appending to the file, instead of overwriting it.

Yes, you've got an open writer. Writing to that writer will just write *additional* text to the file - just like multiple calls to `write` on an `OutputStream` will write additional data to the stream rather than overwriting existing data on each call. Imagine if your code had:

```
fw.write("first");
fw.flush();
fw.write("second");
fw.flush();
```

Would you expect that to replace the entire content of the file with "second"? I wouldn't - and that's exactly what happens if you call `writeToFile` twice.

If you want every call to `writeToFile` to completely replace the content of the file, you should create a new writer, write, then close the writer, within the method.

Personally I'd avoid using `FileWriter` anyway as it writes using the platform-default encoding, which isn't great.

I'd use either [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) which will write a sequence of lines to a file, or [`Files.newBufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) to create a writer for multiple write calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll change it to `BufferedWriter` with a new instance on every call

Comment: @GalAbra: Don't forget to *close* the writer (ideally with a try-with-resources statement) at the end. Or use `Files.write` to just do it all for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you pass `false` for the second parameter of the constructor, `FileWriter` will start off in "rewrite" mode. However, it would continue appending to the same file for as long as you keep using the same `FileWriter` object.

You create `FileWriter` in the initializer of your class, and never replace it with another `FileWriter` after that. This is why it keeps appending to the file.

If you need to replace the file at some point, you have several options:

- **Replace `FileWriter` instance** - you can close the old `FileWriter`, and make a new one instead. The new writer would overwrite the existing file, or
- **Use [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)** - this class lets you "rewind" to the beginning of the file.